# AttributeError at /predict/ Can't get attribute 'artificial_neuron' on <module '__main__'

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I ma trying to create a neural network and link it with my django project, when I call the model it gaves me this error message
AttributeError at /predict/
Can't get attribute 'artificial_neuron' on <module '**main**' from 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\PFE_AYA\Disease_prediction\manage.py'>
then I realised that the model is empty inside when I pickle it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import pandas as pd 
data=pd.read_csv('DATABASE_SPREADSHEET_1 - Copie.csv', sep=';')
X=data.iloc[:,1:].values
y=data.iloc[:,0].values
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

y = y.reshape((y.shape[0], 1))

print('dimensions de X:', X.shape)
print('dimensions de y:', y.shape)

plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap='summer')
plt.show()
def initialisation(X):
    W = np.random.randn(X.shape[1], 1)
    b = np.random.randn(1)
    return (W, b)
def model(X, W, b):
    Z = X.dot(W) + b
    A = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-Z))
    return A
def log_loss(A, y):
    return 1 / len(y) * np.sum(-y * np.log(A) - (1 - y) * np.log(1 - A))
def gradients(A, X, y):
    dW = 1 / len(y) * np.dot(X.T, A - y)
    db = 1 / len(y) * np.sum(A - y)
    return (dW, db)
def update(dW, db, W, b, learning_rate):
    W = W - learning_rate * dW
    b = b - learning_rate * db
    return (W, b)
def predict(X, W, b):
    A = model(X, W, b)
    # print(A)
    return A >= 0.5
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
def artificial_neuron(X, y, learning_rate = 0.1, n_iter = 100):
    # initialisation W, b
    W, b = initialisation(X)

    Loss = []

    for i in range(n_iter):
        A = model(X, W, b)
        Loss.append(log_loss(A, y))
        dW, db = gradients(A, X, y)
        W, b = update(dW, db, W, b, learning_rate)

    y_pred = predict(X, W, b)
    print(accuracy_score(y, y_pred))

    plt.plot(Loss)
    plt.show()

    return (W, b)
W, b = artificial_neuron(X, y)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
ax.scatter(X[:,0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap='summer')

x1 = np.linspace(-1, 4, 100)
x2 = ( - W[0] * x1 - b) / W[1]

ax.plot(x1, x2, c='orange', lw=3)
# Save Model Using Pickle
import pandas
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import pickle
import pickle
# open a file, where you ant to store the data
file = open('model.pkl', 'wb')

# dump information to that file
pickle.dump(model, file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `model` is a function without parameter, you should dump it with the parameters.
If you can use dill, you can dump all things in `main.py`

```py
import dill

def foo():
    return "function can be serialized by dill"
x = "Whatever you want to dump"
d = dict(vars())
with open("data.pkl", "wb") as f:
    dill.dump(d, f)
```

```py
import dill

with open("data.pkl", "rb") as f:
    d = dill.load(f)
for k, v in d.items():
    exec(f"{k} = v")
```

Comment: could you please show me how?

Comment: Well, I found that pickle cannot serialize function. But if you can use [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/), you can dump all things in main.py.

Comment: when I tried to add this code right after my model in the jupiter notebook it gaves me this error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


TypeError: cannot pickle '_hashlib.HASH' object